# Do not know where to start MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have to have the user input 'str'(which is a string) and 'letter'(a letter). The function has to create 'newstr'(a new string) that has all instances of 'letter' removed. There is also another output called 'num' (a number) which displays the number of letters that were actually removed from 'str'.

I cannot figure out where to begin. I think using a while loop and then using if statements and asking whether 'letter' is in 'str' would be the first step but I have no idea what the syntax could be.

CODE THAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:

```
function [newstr, num] = removeLetter(str, letter)
% This program will take the 'str' that the user inputs and will 
% remove all instances of 'letter' from it. It will ignore the case  
% of the letters.
% After it removes all instances of 'letter', it will output the new 
% string
% that is produced (newstr). It will also output the number of that  
% letter taken out of the str.

%Inputs:
% str - string that user inputs
% letter - the letter that should be taken out of the string

% Outputs:
% newstr - the string that is left over after the letters are taken 
%  out
% num - the number of letters taken out of the string

s = 0; %Used for the number of instances of 'letter' that is removed   
% from 'str'

while str == letter
    if
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Stedy I have updated my post with the code that I have tried so far. As I said, I do not know where to even begin.

Comment: you can use strfind/strrep or regular expressions (see regexp)

Comment: @user3011219 I do not understand your question. Please, refer to  help pages of the functions I mentioned